# Android - Udp Communication Over Port 40

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, udp, port

I'm writing a client application to communicate with central device over port 40 with udp.Since i can't change central devices communication port, i'm stuck with port 40.

But i'm unable to do it.I can use other ports, but i can't use ports 40,41,10 and some other 2 digit ports.In stock samsung rom, application was not force closing when i try to use port 40, i switched to cyanogenmod and it now keeps force closing when using port 40.

I find this error pretty weird, does anyone know what can possibly cause this situation ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please post any relavant information like errors or codes to make sure people can help you as best as possible